# SwiftUI Path: upside down and wrong Pivot in Scenekit

Tags: swiftui, scenekit

Problem:
When I parse a SwiftUI Path to Scenekit, it i  upside down and the pivot is outside the bounding box.

I tried:
Setting SwiftUI  .anchorPreference to center. Didn't make any difference.

Goal:
How can I make the pivot the center bottom of the bounding box?

Important: I need to have a correct SwiftUI Path -> SCN Pivot translation, and not manually offsetting the pivot, as this would affect all objects pivot on scene

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct PatternScene: View {
    let idx: Int

    let pattern = Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.pattern
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .anchorPreference(key: MyTextPreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds, transform: { [MyTextPreferenceData(viewIdx: self.idx, bounds: $0)] })
    }
}

struct PatternScene_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PatternScene(idx: 0)
    }
  }
```

[image]

```
 //Connect PatternScene with Scenekit
        let scnpath = PatternScene(idx: 0).pattern.cgPath
        let shape = SCNShape(path: UIBezierPath(cgPath: scnpath), extrusionDepth: 1)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        //material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        material.isDoubleSided = true
        // shape.firstMaterial = material
         let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)
        shapeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        shapeNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)
        shapeNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

UIKit and SwiftUI use a flipped geometry where y values increase as you move from the top to the bottom of the canvas. 
Scenekit does not use flipped geometry. So you have to "flip" the y values...

On a layer you can even set this value...https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410960-geometryflipped ...but i think there is not such a value for scenekit...

Comment: Thanks Chris, I found how to flip the pivot in SceneKit, but I wanted to have the correct correlation between swiftUI Anchor and SceneKit pivot. shapeNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0)